# Cross platform automated testing - Is there a way?

Tags: unit-testing, cross-platform

I have a small library that is ported to different platforms (win, os x, ios, android) that I am using in some small personal utilities and I am starting to look into testing more thoroughly.

Right now, I am using NUnit to test the windows version, with test cases written in c#. The setup just basically loads the dll and the test cases make various calls to the library. I want to duplicate this testing on the other platforms. I know there are other xUnit type frameworks to accomplish this on the other platforms, JUnit etc., but I would rather not have to rewrite the test cases for each platform.

Is there a recommended way to have one set of test cases and just point them to one of the libraries to run against that platform?

I still consider myself a novice programmer, so apologies if it's not possible and the question is naive.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of unit testing(testing individual procedures or functions rather than overall program functionality as in blackbox testing ), and different languages supports different language specific features, there cannot exist a universal unit testing framework that supports *all* programming languages (in your case, Java, C#, Objective-C ). That's why we have xUnit framework for different languages.

Even if someone creates such framework, it would not be possible to properly test functions that uses language specific features.

Comment: So the solution then is to just rewrite each test case in each language?

Comment: Why not use single programming language to write your library? That way you'd only need one set of test suite. If you write your library in C and strictly conform to C standard, you should be able to run your code on all platforms (with some restriction on android. See http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html for more info).